# Accessing Database from command line in Play 2

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, database-connection

I am trying to access Play database from play console by calling a method in the controller.
As Play application is not running, the database is not initialized.
I figured it out one way to get the database access is using FakeApplication 
But, FakeApplicationis mainly for testing. MY aim to fix some problems in the production database using a simple method

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps i made for you.

1.
          * 1

```
        Start by logging in to your database server.
      * 2

        Next, go to "Start, Programs, Accessories" and then to "Command Prompt."
      *

        Sponsored Links
            o Network Security Scanner

              Don't Let Hackers Access Info From Your Business Network. Try it Free!
              www.gfi.com/LanGuard_2014
      * 3

        Type "Show Databases" on the command line.
      * 4

        Choose your database from the list of databases and type it on the command line. Press "Enter." A query will run to provide you access to your own database.
      * 5

        Manage the data or commands that you would like to use as soon as you have entered your password and are officially logged in.
      * 6

        Play with the options to manage and operate your database. Set the database up to your personal preferences so navigating and managing the database will be as simple as possible.
```

Comment: Could you please ans? :)

Comment: Yes it is a fully legit answer

Comment: What you have posted ?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're trying to fix issues with a database in production, it's probably easier/wiser to access the database using the tooling provided by the database.  Most popular databases have sufficient GUI and/or command line tools which would offer more functionality than simply going through the Play console and using JDBC or some other library.

Comment: True. but Think this as a batch job in Play framework. How to run it ?